# Displaying contents of an object in the query result

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following code in java:

```
    try {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query userQuery=session.createQuery("select u.userId, u.username,p.profileContent from User as u inner join u.profiles as p");//, p.profileContent 

        List userList=userQuery.list();
        for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(userList.get(i));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
```

I am trying to display the result of the query but only the object is displayed. Can you suggest me the way to display the contents of the objects. Currently i am getting result like:

> [Ljava.lang.Object;@64bef361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you try to print any object reference, it's toString() method is called. Now, suppose your userList is of type User. You have not overridden toString() method in your User class. So, what's happening currently is toString() method of object class is called.The Object class has implemented this method in such a way that it prints it's fully qualified package name and it's hashcode.

So, simply override this toString() method in your User class and it will start printing entire data as you have configured in this method. You can manually override this method, or if you have an IDE line netbeans or eclipse, just right click anywhere in the java file and select generate ToString method.

Comment: the problem in my case is that I am trying to display the result of the SQL query, which is the combination of two different tables. So, the SQL query returns the result with the combination of columns from two different tables. This is the reason I cannot use the toString() method of the particular class because I have fields from two different tables. For your information, I am using hibernate persistence

Comment: Fine...But what is the type of your userlist object?You must be having an hibernate entity mapped for the type of that list,isn't it?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I did not know the result of the query joining more than one tables will store the result as array of Objects class.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (Object o : userList) {
    Object[] row = (Object[]) o;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

But you should probably use a debugger instead of cluttering your code with such loops.

Comment: You could also write a method that does exactly the same thing and introduces no clutter.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, good programming practice is to override `Object.toString()` So that you avoid this problem. If you want more meaningful output then what you are getting, then adhere to the standards that are encouraged by the API.[refer to the documentation when in doubt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: How is he supposed to override toString for an array?

Comment: I'm sorry, but who said the OP is retrieving an array? I assumed that in 20012 we don't use arrays. Regardless of the past or present it is stated in almost any beginner tutorial to  override `Java.lang.Object.toDtring()`

Comment: He said it... `[Ljava.lang.Object;@64bef361`

Comment: Note that that he says that is what he is getting and I am providing an answer for his question and not for his answer. Besides SO questions are not individualistic and my answer remains for a broader audience who may have same issue (based on the question and not the OP's posting on what messages he gets).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I did not know the result of the query joining more than one tables will store the result as array of Objects class.

```
Query userQuery=session.createQuery("select u.userId, u.username,p.profileContent from User as u inner join u.profiles as p");//, p.profileContent 

Iterator ite = userQuery.list().iterator();
while ( ite.hasNext() ) {    
    Object[] pair = (Object[]) ite.next();
    Integer user = (Integer) pair[0];
    String userName=(String) pair[1];
    String profileContent=(String) pair[2];

    System.out.println(user+" "+userName+" "+profileContent);
}
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with the joining.  It has to do with the fact that you asked for a "scalar" result (select u.userId, u.username,p.profileContent).